# noUiSlider does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make noUiSlider work and not getting past the first step. Below is the simplest file I am trying, and it just gives me a blank screen:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="It is really easy to use noUiSlider, simply include the files and call the plugin. Find out more!">

    <title>noUiSlider - Getting Started | Refreshless.com</title>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="/assets/base.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/assets/prism.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="/nouislider/source/distribute/jquery.nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/nouislider/source/distribute/jquery.nouislider.pips.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="/nouislider/source/distribute/jquery.nouislider.all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(function() {                        
   $("#noUiSlider").noUiSlider({
       handles: 2,
       connect: true,
       scale:[10,30],
       start:[0,60]
   });
});
</script>
</body>
```

What am I doing wrong? I thought I followed the examples on the website.

Comment: you don't have any element with `#noUiSlider`

Comment: It's working http://jsbin.com/xedul/1/edit?html,output

Comment: I cut and paste your code exactly into an html file, but still get just a blank page. Must be missing something else.

Comment: what errors do you see in your console ?

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/6.2.0/jquery.nouislider.all.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
file://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
nui%20-%20Copy.html:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: try this http://jsbin.com/xedul/2/edit

Comment: Still similar errors. Here is the console log. BTW, thanks much for the continued help.

Comment: GET file://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
nui%20-%20Copy.html:9 GET file://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
jquery.nouislider.min.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Link' of undefined
nui - Copy.html:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: I can't convert the discussion to chat, since I don't have enough reputation. Dhiraj, would appreciate if you can.

Comment: looks like i cannot create it too because of your rep. Okay, heres the deal. All the links that you see in your HTML page make sure they have `http`  appended to them. That's the only error

Comment: Managed to get it working by copying the jquery files to local directory.

Comment: Will try what you suggested as well, but thanks again for all the help

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `div` element on your body that has an id, let's say "slider". Then use `var slider = document.getElementById('slider')`and the function instead of what you have should be `noUiSlider.create(slider, {` where the "slider" inside the brackets will be name of the variable you have initialised as the element on your HTML code.

Hope it helps